# Working as a physiotherapist in France

Tags: france, working, paperwork, medical, qualifications

A friend of mine wants to work in France as a physiotherapist.
She is a citizen of Hungary and she is currently working as a physiotherapist. She has a bachelor degree in a related field.

With these conditions, to be allowed to work as a physiotherapist in France,

- what documents should she prepare?
- and what permissions from which institutions should she obtain to allow her to work in France in this particular field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a citizen from a member of the European Union, there are no particular problems to work in France.

https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F2651

The French title for physiotherapist is *kinésithérapeute*. To work as a *kinésithérapeute* in France, you need an official diploma. If you are from another country, you need to check whether the diploma obtained is recognized as equivalent in France.

This document http://www.ordremk.fr/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/Guide_CNOMK.pdf seems to mention that the Hungarian three-year diploma is considered equivalent to the French one:

> La validation des diplômes délivrés par les 4 universités  hongroises
>   correspondent bien au diplôme français. Ces facultés de médecine sont
>   situées à Budapest, Szeged, Pécs, Debrecen.

I would consider soliciting the French embassy in Hungary to check the diploma equivalence.

Notice that the candidate must also be able to speak/write French sufficiently to deal with customers and administration.